# How can I select all in linq to sql

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

In my LINQ query, I am trying to select all if a value is `null`:

```
var filteredLesson = (from l in storeDB.lessons
                      where l.statusID == SUBMITTED ||
                            l.statusID == APPROVED &&
                            l.projectID == (l.projectID.HasValue 
                                ? lesson.projectID : /*select all*/  )
                      select l).ToList();
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Could you explain what does **select all** achieve in your case ?

Comment: by select all I mean if the integer value l.projectID is null then I want to select every integer value for l.projectID

Comment: in other words, get records with projectIDs matching your `lesson` AND the nulls ? Please give more information; structure it in a sentence so the answerers will know exactly what you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
var filteredLesson = (from l in storeDB.lessons
                      where
                          (l.statusID == SUBMITTED || l.statusID == APPROVED)
                          &&
                          (!l.projectID.HasValue || l.projectID == lesson.projectID)
                      select l
                     ).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks went with something similar <code>  var filteredLesson = (from l in storeDB.lessons
                                      where !lesson.projectID.HasValue &&   
                                            (l.statusID == SUBMITTED || l.statusID == APPROVED)  ||
                                            l.projectID == lesson.projectID &&(l.statusID == SUBMITTED || l.statusID == APPROVED) 
                                      select l).ToList(); </code>

Comment: @crocaduck81 - ah yes, fixed the missing status filter, since it is common to both paths you can have it separate AND-ed with the projectID part.

Answer (score 3):

You just want to compare it to itself if the value is `null`.  That way your row will be included in the results if the value is `null`.

```
var filteredLesson = (from l in storeDB.lessons
                      where l.statusID == SUBMITTED ||
                      l.statusID == APPROVED &&
                      l.projectID == (l.projectID.HasValue 
                                   ? lesson.projectID : l.projectID )
                      select l).ToList();
```

Comment: This is more correct than the best answer. Note that the best answer is selects all the lessons without a projectID and those with the matching projectID that matches the statusID's. Note that operator precendence with the && and || will not give you the results you are expecting. See my post below.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your object model it's hard to be totally sure about this, but I imagine something like the following should be what you're looking for:

```
var filteredLesson = storeDB.lessons
                            .Where(l => (l.statusID == SUBMITTED
                                       || l.statusID == APPROVED)
                                       && !l.projectID.HasValue)
                            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's are many of the above answers written up using xUnit.Net tests. Note that the original author's comment in the answer he selected (which is an incorrect solution) gives the results he expected. I cleaned up his solution to remove the duplicate comparisons.

> Sample values are at the bottom.

```
    public class SelectAllInLinq2SqlTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Unsuccessful()
        {
            var filteredLesson =
                (from l in Lessons
                 where l.statusID == SUBMITTED ||
                       l.statusID == APPROVED &&
                       l.projectID == (l.projectID.HasValue ? projectOne : l.projectID)
                 select l).ToList();

            Assert.Equal(4, filteredLesson.Count);

            // this returned 5 items!
            // good - filtered the null project IDs and statusID == SUBMITTED
            // good - filtered the null project IDs and statusID == APPROVED
            // good - filtered the projectID == projectOne and statusID == SUBMITTED
            // good - filtered the projectID == projectOne and statusID == APPROVED
            // FAIL - filtered the projectID == projectTwo !!!

            // two failures first selecting all records containing a null projectID and any status (we wanted to filter on SUBMITTED or APPROVED)
            // the failure is due to operator precedence the 'l.statusID == SUBMITTED ||' is short-circuiting the rest of the comparison
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Unsuccessful2()
        {
            var filteredLesson =
                (from l in Lessons
                 where !l.projectID.HasValue ||
                       (l.statusID == SUBMITTED || l.statusID == APPROVED && l.projectID == projectOne)
                 select l).ToList();

            Assert.Equal(4, filteredLesson.Count);

            // this returned 6 items!
            // good - filtered the null project IDs and statusID == SUBMITTED
            // good - filtered the null project IDs and statusID == APPROVED
            // FAIL - filtered the null project IDs and statusID == OTHER!
            // good - filtered the projectID == projectOne and statusID == SUBMITTED
            // good - filtered the projectID == projectOne and statusID == APPROVED
            // FAIL - filtered the projectID == projectTwo !!!

            // Two failures:
            //   first selecting all records containing a null projectID and any status (we wanted to filter on SUBMITTED or APPROVED)
            //   second failure is due to operator precedence the 'l.statusID == SUBMITTED ||' is short-circuiting the rest of the comparison
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Unsuccessful2NotQuiteFixed()
        {
            var filteredLesson =
                (from l in Lessons
                 where !l.projectID.HasValue
                       || ((l.statusID == SUBMITTED || l.statusID == APPROVED)
                           && l.projectID == projectOne)
                 select l).ToList();

            Assert.Equal(4, filteredLesson.Count);
            // this returned 5 items!
            // good - filtered the null project IDs and statusID == SUBMITTED
            // good - filtered the null project IDs and statusID == APPROVED
            // FAIL - filtered the null project IDs and statusID == OTHER!
            // good - filtered the projectID == projectOne and statusID == SUBMITTED with a SUBMITTED status
            // good - filtered the projectID == projectOne and statusID == APPROVED with a APPROVED status

            // failures selecting all records containing a null projectID and any status (we wanted to filter on SUBMITTED or APPROVED)
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Sucessful()
        {
            // Questioner's provided solution...

            var filteredLesson =
                (from l in Lessons
                 where !l.projectID.HasValue && (l.statusID == SUBMITTED || l.statusID == APPROVED)
                       || l.projectID == projectOne && (l.statusID == SUBMITTED || l.statusID == APPROVED)
                 select l).ToList();

            Assert.Equal(4, filteredLesson.Count);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void SucessfulRefined()
        {
            // cleaned up without the duplicate status comparisons. Note the parens are necessary.

            var filteredLesson =
                (from l in Lessons
                 where (!l.projectID.HasValue || l.projectID == projectOne)
                       && (l.statusID == SUBMITTED || l.statusID == APPROVED)
                 select l).ToList();

            Assert.Equal(4, filteredLesson.Count);
        }

        public class Lesson
        {
            public int? projectID { get; set; }
            public int statusID { get; set; }
        }

        const int OTHER = 0;
        const int SUBMITTED = 1;
        const int APPROVED = 2;

        const int projectOne = 1;

        Lesson[] Lessons = new[]
                          {
                              new Lesson { projectID = null, statusID = SUBMITTED},
                              new Lesson { projectID = null, statusID = APPROVED},
                              new Lesson { projectID = null, statusID = OTHER},
                              new Lesson { projectID = 1, statusID = SUBMITTED},
                              new Lesson { projectID = 1, statusID = APPROVED},
                              new Lesson { projectID = 1, statusID = OTHER},
                              new Lesson { projectID = 2, statusID = SUBMITTED},
                              new Lesson { projectID = 2, statusID = APPROVED},
                              new Lesson { projectID = 2, statusID = OTHER},
                          };
    }
}
```